# How to use ColorFilter when the value is only true?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am trying to use ColorFilter when recommend is only true

```
GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                recommend = !recommend;
                if (!recommend) {
                  both = false;
                  male = false;
                  female = false;
                }
              });
            },
            child: ColorFiltered(
              colorFilter: recommend
                  ? ColorFilter.mode(Colors.amber, BlendMode.saturation)
                  : ColorFilter.mode(Colors.white, BlendMode.saturation),)
```

How can i use CololrFilter when the recommend is only true ??

Comment: `colorFilter: recommend ? ColorFilter.mode(Colors.amber, BlendMode.saturation) : null,)`

Comment: sadly null doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
colorFilter: recommend
              ? ColorFilter.mode(Colors.amber, BlendMode.saturation)
              : ColorFilter.mode(Colors.transparent, BlendMode.saturation),)
```